# Computer Architecture in dialog script

Tags: scripting, dialog

I would like to make a program with dialog that shows my ComputerArchitecture. But i have some false outputs.
This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash 
# ComputerArchitecture_interactive_dialog: an interactive dialog to see the ComputerArchitecture in a simple way.

DIALOG_CANCEL=1
DIALOG_ESC=255
HEIGHT=0
WIDTH=0

display_result() {
  dialog --title "$1" \
    --no-collapse \
    --msgbox "$result" 0 0
}

while true; do
  exec 3>&1
  selection=$(dialog \
    --backtitle "Computer Architecture list" \
    --title "ComputerArchitectuur" \
    --clear \
    --cancel-label "Exit" \
    --menu "Use [ENTER] to select:" $HEIGHT $WIDTH 4 \
    "1" "Information about Processors and Cores" \
    "2" "Information about RAM-memory" \
    "3" "Information about connected drives and USB-devices" \
    "4" "Inforamtion about the current load" \ 
    2>&1 1>&3)
  exit_status=$?
  exec 3>&-
  case $exit_status in
    $DIALOG_CANCEL)
      clear
      echo "Program stopped."
      exit
      ;;
    $DIALOG_ESC)
      clear
      echo "Program closed." >&2
  exit 1
  ;;
  esac
  case $selection in
    0 )
      clear
      echo "Program stopped."
      ;;
    1 )
      result=$(echo "Processors and Cores"; lscpu)
      display_result "Processors and Cores"
      ;;
    2 )
      result=$(echo "RAM"; dmicode --type 17)
      display_result "RAM"
      ;;
    3 )
     result=$(echo "Connected drives and USB-devices";lsblk \lsusb)
     display_result "Connected drives and USB-devices"
     ;;
   4 )
     result=$(echo "Current load"; top)
     display_result "Current load"
     ;;
 esac
done
```

and this is the false output:

```
Error: Expected 2 arguments, found only 1. 
Use --help to list options.
```

Comment: add `set -x` to the top of your script (below the hash bang) and find out what command is causing that error.

Answer (score 3):

You need to double-quote your process substitions.  All of them.  You also need to double-quote your variables when you use them (again, all of them - $selection, $HEIGHT, $WIDTH, $DIALOG_CANCEL, $DIALOG_ESC, and any other variable you use).

e.g. don't do this:

```
result=$(echo "Processors and Cores"; lscpu)
```

do this:

```
result="$(echo "Processors and Cores"; lscpu)"
```

And don't do:

```
case $selection in
```

do this:

```
case "$selection" in
```

Better yet, rewrite your `display_result` function so that it doesn't rely on a global variable (`$result`).

e.g. something like:

```
display_result() {
  # This version of display_result takes multiple args.
  # The first is the title.  The rest are displayed in the 
  # message box, with a newline between each arg.
  # To insert a blank line use an empty string '' between any two args.
  title="$1" ; shift

  dialog --title "$title" \
    --no-collapse \
    --msgbox "$(printf "%s\n" "$@")" 0 0
}
```

Then, in your case statements, you'd use it like this:

```
...
case "$selection" in
  1) display_result 'Processors and Cores' "$(lscpu)" ;;
  2) display_result 'RAM' "$(dmicode --type 17)" ;;
  ...
esac
```